# How to replace apostrophe character in Unix

Tags: unix, replace, sed, character

My file contains an apostrophe (`’`). I am able to see this character if the file opens in Windows but not able to see it if the file opens in Unix. But I need to use that file once after removing that character.

I can't use windows to remove the character manually. My servers are Unix so I need to remove the character at that point. I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```
cat HAllResponses_11004*.txt| sed 's/’/'/g;'>HAllResponses_11004_1.txt
```

1. How to identify that character if that character is not appearing.
2. How to replace that character if that character is not appering.

---

Your 3 Answers are not helping me to resolve the issue.
when i use hexa values it is giving as below.

$ echo -e "compilin\xe2\x80\x99 my program"

compilinâ my program

The problem is when i paste apostrophe in unix, it is appearing as '.'

Pl help me

Comment: Did you try what I've suggested?

Answer (score 1):

The `’` character is different from the `'` character. To see that more clearly, inspect their hexadecimal value:

```
echo -n ’ | hexdump -C
00000000  e2 80 99                                          |...|
00000003
echo -n \' | hexdump -C
00000000  27                                                |'|
00000001
```

Now the `’` can be identified by its hex value when using `sed` or similar tools for replacing it inside a sequence:

```
echo -e "compilin\xe2\x80\x99 my program"
compilin’ my program
echo -e "compilin\xe2\x80\x99 my program" | sed "s|\xe2\x80\x99|'|"
compilin' my program
```

This will replace the apostrophe character only if it occurs in the text. In your case simply pass the filename as the second argument to `sed` and you're done:

```
sed -i "s|\xe2\x80\x99|'|" HAllResponses_11004_1.txt
```

or just:

```
sed -i "s|’|'|" HAllResponses_11004_1.txt
```

Comment: Your 3 Answers are not helping me to resolve the issue. when i use hexa values it is giving as below.

$ echo -e "compilin\xe2\x80\x99 my program"

compilinâ my program

The problem is when i paste apostrophe in unix, it is appearing as '.'

Pl help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use cat -vet to see the control characters in unix and then use sed to replace those characters. In the example below, cat -vet shows (') as (M-^R) which can be easliy replaced using sed.

Original File:

```
My file contains an apostrophe (’). I am able to see this character if the file opens in Windows but not able to see it if the file opens in Unix. But I need to use that file once after removing that character.
I can't use windows to remove the character manually. My servers are Unix so I need to remove the character at that point. I have tried the following but it didn't work.
```

Control characters shown with cat -vet in Unix:

```
/home/temp_files > cat -vet SO.txt
My file contains an apostrophe (M-^R). I am able to see this character if the file opens in Windows but not able to see it if the file opens in Unix. But I need to use that file once after removing that character.$
I can't use windows to remove the character manually. My servers are Unix so I need to remove the character at that point. I have tried the following but it didn't work.$
```

Replace with sed:

```
/home/temp_files > cat -vet SO.txt  | sed 's/M-^R//g'
My file contains an apostrophe (). I am able to see this character if the file opens in Windows but not able to see it if the file opens in Unix. But I need to use that file once after removing that character.$
I can't use windows to remove the character manually. My servers are Unix so I need to remove the character at that point. I have tried the following but it didn't work.$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find-replace `'` using `sed` (note that you need to escape special characters)

```
$ cat a.txt
This line don't have a '
This is test

$ sed s/\'//g a.txt
This line dont have a
This is test

$ sed s/\'/\"/g a.txt
This line don"t have a "
This is test
```

If you want to edit the file in-place, you can use the following syntax (note that the contents of `a.txt` will be modified after execution of the command)

```
$ sed -i s/\'/\"/g a.txt
```